# Number of ways to roll five 6-sided dice with sum 7

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I would like to determine the number of possible outcomes that  are possible to roll five fair $6$-sided dice where the sum of the faces adds up to $7$. I am interested in the case where order does matter, for example if the dice were arranged in $3,1,1,1,1$ they can also be arranged as $1,3,1,1,1$, etc.

Edit: So far the only possible solution I can find is to write out the combinations of five numbers (between $1-6$) that when summed will give a value of $7$. Then for each of the combinations I was attempting to find the number of ways which this combination could be formed. This was very long-some since I don't know an easy way to do this. For example is there a formula to describe the number of ways the numbers $1,2,2,1,1$ can be rearranged? I would then have to apply this formula to each of the combinations of numbers. I was hoping somebody could explain an easier way.

Thank you.

Comment: Ah sorry, this was my first post. I have actually taken this as an analogy of a thermal statistical question I am doing about the micro states of a system. I will put an edit in the main text.

Comment: There are only two types, a $3$ and the rest $1$, or two $2$ and the rest $1$. If order does not matter we are finished. If it does matter, there are $\binom{5}{1}$ of the first type and $\binom{5}{2}$ of the second type.

Comment: The general formula for arranging items in sequence, where some of the items are identical to others, is given in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/623877/rigorous-proof-combinatorics-problem-the-number-of-ways-to-arrange-n-object  As a special case, if you have a sequence containing just $a$ ones and $b$ twos, the number of ways to arrange these $a + b$ items is $(a+b)!/(a!b!)$.

Answer (score 4):

Each die always has value at least $1$, so we may as well ask for the number of ordered sequences $(a_1, \ldots, a_5)$ such that $a_1, \ldots, a_5 \in \{0, \ldots, 5\}$ and $a_1 + \cdots + a_5 = 2$. This is only possible if (1) one of the $a_i$ is $2$ and the others are all $0$, or (2) two of the $a_i$ are $1$ and the others are all $0$. There are only ${5 \choose 1} = 5$ possibilities for the form and ${5 \choose 2} = 10$ possibilities for the latter, and so only $5 + 10 = 15$ ordered sequences satisfying the criteria in total.

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to obtain a sum of 7 from five six-sided dice, where order *doesn't* matter: (3, 1, 1, 1, 1) and (2, 2, 1, 1, 1).  In how many ways can you rearrange each of these?  Figure out these numbers and add them together to get the total number of possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

There are not many possible outcomes, actually.

One "big" group of outcomes is the one you mentioned: one "3" and the other dice "1", in which case you have 5 posibilities ( depending on the position of the dice with "3" on top).

The other group consists of the outcomes with two "2"'s and the other dice with "1". In this case the number of posibilities depends on the position of the "2"'s only, because then you know the rest must be "1"'s .
So the number of posibities is the number of posible positions of the two "2"'s.
It is $\binom{5}{2} $ which is a combinatorial number , see:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination for an explanation.

And that's it, because any other possible outcome would add up more than 7.

Answer (score 0):

15 ways

Write 7 as 1+1+1+1+1+1+1

See + sign as blank space now we place 4 patrician

1 | 1+1| 1| 1+1 | 1

1,2,1,2,1

So basically we have 
To place 4 patrician in 6 vacant place

6C4=15